# In Coffeescript stack traces have inconsistent file names and line numbers

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Example code:

```
Error.prepareStackTrace = (_, stack) -> stack

test = ->
    err = new Error()
    console.log err.stack[1].getFileName(), ":", err.stack[1].getLineNumber()

test()
```

This prints `path\to\file.coffee : 14`, where 14 apparently references the generated JS file. Is there any way to fix this?

I would be happy to either have a CS line number and a path to the CS file or the same for JS.

Comment: Source maps might help in a debugger but probably not with an `Error` instance.

Comment: Just googled this lib: [coffee-trace](https://github.com/xenomuta/coffee-trace). Looks pretty good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known issue.

The problem is that node.js have no support for source maps yet.

But there are several third-party solutions for this problem, e.g.:

- [`coffee-trace` module](https://github.com/xenomuta/coffee-trace)
- [generic `source-map-support` module](https://github.com/evanw/node-source-map-support)
- [`coffee-script-mapped` shell util](https://github.com/Illniyar/coffee-script-mapped)

I haven't tried any of this modules myself, but they looks fine.